# How do i pass a file location as a param in java

Tags: java, parameters

```
private static void saveCallers(String fName, RadioShow r) throws IOException {
        //TODO write the code to save the callers to a file
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Desktop\\text1.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);
            out.writeObject(r);
            out.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("something went wrong here! : " + e);
        }

        }
```

Its giving me a URLClassLoaderException, so i presume im giving it an incorrect format? But i cant seem to figure out the correct way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: URLClassLoaderException? What is this exception?

Comment: Add the actual exception message and the stack trace - that's the most important information.

Comment: URClassLoader Exception ? Your code doesn't seem to have any URL kinda of stuff. Please post the entire code.

Comment: Could you include the stack trace?

Comment: I guess, a another "homework" guy who doesn't know what and where he's posting. [:P]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "C:\Desktop\" folder exists.